# Cant find the right syntax?

Tags: c#

```
public static void CopyProperties<T1, T2>(T1 objA, T2 objB) where T1 : new()
{
}
```

The above signature for this method compiles, however I also want to add the same 'new' conditional for `T2`

Signatures ive tried but dont work:

```
  public static void CopyProperties<T1, T2>(T1 objA, T2 objB) where T1, T2 : new()
  public static void CopyProperties<T1, T2>(T1 objA, T2 objB) where T1 : new(), where T2 : new()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public static void CopyProperties<T1, T2>(T1 objA, T2 objB) 
    where T1 : new()
    where T2 : new()
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add the constraint at the end:

```
public static void CopyProperties<T1, T2>(T1 objA, T2 objB) where T1 : new() where T2 : new()
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 public static void CopyProperties<T1, T2>(T1 objA, T2 objB) 
 where T1 : new() 
 where T2 : new()
```

Answer (score 0):

This code extract will give you what you are looking for, it's important to use the where key word for each type you want to add constraints for, the new key word needs to be last constraint on each type. Here is an example

```
static void CopyProperties<T1, T2>(T1 objA, T2 objB) 
            where T1 : class, new()
            where T2 : class, new()
```